# Data structure to represent mapping of intervals

Tags: scala, data-structures

Here is a function which can deduce the status of a person given their age

```scala
def getStatus(age: Int): String = {
  age match {
    case age if 0 until 2 contains age => "infant"
    case age if 2 until 10 contains age => "child"
    case age if 10 until 18 contains age => "teen"
    case _ => "adult"
  }
}
```

Let's say the boundaries can change. We can decide a person can be considered as an infant until 3 years old. As they change we do not want the boundaries to be hard coded and they will be stored externally.

What is a data-structure that can store mappings based on an interval?

Something like

```scala
val intervalMap = IntervalMap(
  (0, 2) -> "infant",
  (2, 10) -> "child",
  (10, 18) -> "teen",
  (18, 200 ) -> "adult"
)
intervalMap(1) // "infant"
intervalMap(12) // "teen"
```

I'm developping in Scala but a language agnostic answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: In this case you only need to store upper or lower bound, not both. So ordered List[(Int, String)] is suitable, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Easy Answer**

There isn't anything in the Scala standard library that does that, but if the number of "categories" is low like in your example, there's no harm in implementing a naive **O(N)** `apply` method on your `IntervalMap` class.

```scala
def apply(in: Int) = categories.collectFirst { 
  case ((min, max), value) if in >= min && in < max => value 
}
```

**Guava**

Looks like the Guava library has a [`RangeMap`](https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html) class that seems to fit your use-case.

**Fancier DIY Idea**

To get a **O(log N)** lookup characteristic, you could represent your category data as a binary tree:

- Each node defines a `min` and `max`
- Root node represents the absolute minimum to the absolute maximum, e.g. `Int.MinValue` to `Int.MaxValue`
- Leaf nodes define a `value` (e.g. `"child"`)
- Non-leaf nodes define a `split` value, where the left child's `max` will be equal to the `split`, and the right child's `min` will be equal to the split
- Find values in the tree by traversing left/right depending on whether your input number (e.g. `age`) is greater than or less than the current node's `split`

You'd have to deal with balancing the tree as it gets built... and TBH this is probably how Guava's doing it under the hood (I did not look into the implementation)